# I'm looking for a book

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember any names of characters. But it was about a boy that gets adopted, or has to work as a builder, or clockwork repair person or something. And it also had a small cube prison that his father was in.  know this is vague, and might not be answerable. but... I hope someone knows it. Also, I think it was teen rated.

Comment: How about you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) it's tried and tested and will help jog your memory to allow you to [edit] in any more details.

Comment: It sounds a tad like incarceron by catherine fisher, but the details are off. Good luck with your search!